# エクセルのセル内で改行された文章を正規表現でマッチさせたい

Tags: python, 正規表現, openpyxl

五月雨の質問申し訳ございません。
エクセルの各セルに入力された文章の末尾に 。 がついているか、ついていないかを判断するプログラムを作ろうとしております。

セル内で改行されていない一行の文章であれば以下コードで判断することが出来ました。
しかし、同じ文章でも改行されている場合同じコードでは判断することが出来ませんでした。

コード

```
import openpyxl
import re

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"sample.xlsx")

ws = wb.active
source = ws["A8"].value


pattern = r"(①.*?)(。)(②.*?)(。)"

if re.search(pattern, source):
    print("でた")
```

#--- A8セルに1行で記述(改行なし)----
A8
①てすと。②てすと。

実行結果
でた

#--- A8セルに2行で記述(改行あり)----
A8
①てすと。
②てすと。
実行結果
出力なし

セル内で改行した文章でも文章の末尾に 。がついているか、ついていないか 判断するコードを作成することは可能でしょうか。
初歩的な質問とは思いますが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

以下の記述で出来そうでした。お騒がせしました。

```
pattern = r"(①.*?)(。)(|\n)(②.*?)(。)"
```